# extract-text-webpack-plugin doesn't load css in dynamically loaded chunks

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-3, extract-text-plugin

I'm working on a multi-entry web app & building with webpack 3, with using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to separate entries' css in separate files.

Currently, I'm trying to load some modules dynamically along with their own css to enhance performance, so I used the plugin's `allChunks: false` option with using the `style-loader` as a `fallback`, which works fine when the css file is being required in dynamic modules only, or non-dynamic entry-points only,

I've made a [sample project](https://github.com/abdelhady/extract-text-webpack-plugin-dynamic-chunk-issue) to demonstrate this issue, so let's assume the following entries:

- `entry2`: `dynamic.css` should be part of the extracted css `entry2.css` --> which works fine
- `entry1`: `dynamic.css` should be part of the dynamically imported chunk `dynamic.js`,
  where the contents of `dynamic.css` will be injected in page with `style-loader` --> This doesn't work, instead `dynamic.css` is totally gone

I've already [opened an issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/818) on plugin's github repo, but it seems that they are focusing on webpack 4 more than webpack 3, so I'm not expecting they would respond to my issue!

### Question is

Is there a workaround to load this shared css dynamically (overcoming this reported issue)?

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. I'll take a look.

Comment: What version of node and NPM are you running on? (the webpack command errors out for me - i suspect my versions of node or npm are the cause)

couple warnings on install: 
npm WARN css-loader@2.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN extractcssissue@1.0.0 No repository field.

Comment: the error I get when running webpack from your github repo: 

webpack
(node:60830) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
(node:60830) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.apply is deprecated. Call apply on the plugin directly instead
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:824
  throw new Error(
  ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead

Comment: Thanks for looking it up, I'm using Node V10.0.0, npm V6.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I've forked your example and am playing around with it. Take a look at this instead though: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#extracting-css-based-on-entry - Pretty sure that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @nstanard I know about the `mini-css-extract-plugin`, but it is for webpack4 only, & I'm using webpack3, & upgrading webpack to 4 is not a quick task by any means. Anyway, I do appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Well, I've made a small change so you can build the project using `npm run build` (which will use the webpack version from `package.json`) instead of running the normal `webpack` build command (which uses the globally installed webpack)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187597/discussion-between-nstanard-and-abdelhady).